# Obfuscating the Crypto.JS passphrase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I am using Crypto.js in a project, I would like to be able to protect the password by obfuscating it, can this be done with crypto.js?

On Node.JS

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off to consider the password a config variable and treat it the same way you treat your other sensitive info - the DB connection info for example.

I like [this tutorial](http://www.chovy.com/node-js/managing-config-variables-inside-a-node-js-application/) which shows how you can get different config values for different environments that your node app runs in.

Answer (score 0):

CryptoJS is an encryption library. You can certainly store an encrypted passphrase and the key that was used to encrypt the passphrase beside it. I would call that obfuscation. It's a very weak type of obfuscation, but it is one.